# spring-boot-starter-ws performance when run as jar

Tags: spring, maven, soap, spring-boot, spring-ws

We've noticed in our that SOAP web-services seem to run faster when run as

```
spring-boot:run
```

as opposed to packaging up the JAR as we do for deployment and running

```
java -jar mySpringApp.jar
```

The speed up is in the order of 2-3x so obviously we would like this for our live environment.

To validate that this wasn't something in our app I've tried this with the sample app from the [spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/)

git source https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-soap-service.git

Testing this with JMeter shows the same sort of speed up.  I've tested this on both Windows 7 Java 1.8.0_31 and Ubuntu 14.04 platforms with 1.8.0_45-b14.

This only seems to be the case for soap services, simple html doesn't show any significant difference in performance.  Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: In investigating this I've already tried swapping out tomcat for jetty and running the exploded JAR but neither of these had any significant impact.

Comment: I've also tested it in my Mac, and had the same behaviour. I'm really curious about this, and maybe will find some time in the weekend to do some debug. Have you tried jvisualvm to check diferences in jvm? Like max heap size, gc activity? Maybe attach a profiler to check where the time is being spent

Comment: Thanks Paulo, I'm glad someone else has been able to reproduce this.  There is maybe a little more GC activity in the java -jar launched variant but running it in the profiler I can see that more than 10% of execution time is in org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarURLConnection.throwFileNotFound(), I can't see this class being called at all when running as spring-boot:run.  Does spring-boot:run deal with JAR/class loading in a different way?  I'll take a further look over the weekend.

Comment: Class loading is quite different when using `java -jar` as Boot needs to handle loading classes from jars nested inside your application jar's `lib` directory. I've opened a [Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3640) so that we can investigate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested this and it appears that the application spends a significant amount of time in the following two code paths:

```
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader$1.hasMoreElements(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:110)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:354)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:327)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:323)
at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:299)
at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:106)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.<init>(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:68)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.newTransformer(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:420)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:106)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:69)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:128)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:60)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:92)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:87)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
```

and

```
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader$1.hasMoreElements(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:110)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:354)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:293)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:289)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:267)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:120)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.<init>(SAX2DOM.java:74)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.output.TransletOutputHandlerFactory.getSerializationHandler(TransletOutputHandlerFactory.java:199)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:436)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:342)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:399)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:69)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:128)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:60)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:92)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:87)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
```

The interesting lines are

```
at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:106)
```

and

```
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:120)
```

What this means is that for every request, the SAAJ implementation in the JRE requests a new `TransformerFactory` and a new `DocumentBuilderFactory`. These factories are located using the [JDK 1.3 service provider discovery mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider), which involves searching for certain resources under `META-INF/services`. The performance of that search is very sensitive to the characteristics of the class loaders from which these resources are looked up. That is why you see a difference between `mvn spring-boot:run` and using an executable JAR. In particular, the executable JAR contains embedded JARs and looking up resources from these embedded JARs is expensive. For `mvn spring-boot:run` this is not the case, which explains why it is faster.

Since this is ultimately a problem with the SAAJ implementation, one solution is to use [Apache Axiom](http://ws.apache.org/axiom/) instead. To do this with the sample application from the spring guide, simply add the following code to `WebServiceConfig`:

```
    @Bean
    public SoapMessageFactory messageFactory() {
        return new AxiomSoapMessageFactory();
    }
```

You also need to add the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>
```