# Spring Boot alternative way to package microservice (not jars in jar)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I analyzed our app performance and found issues with the way we package Spring boot app (and we just do `gradle bootRepackage`).

The problem that Sun WS implementation thinks it is cheap to read content from classpath (they don't do any caching!) and app spend a lot of time in search  for and read of resources in **zip of zip** archives. Example of issue is [spring-boot-starter-ws performance when run as jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730050/spring-boot-starter-ws-performance-when-run-as-jar)

How I can package Spring Boot app without using **jars in jar**? How to make flat jar or how to tell to unpack **fat jar** as it is done with WAR files inside containers?

**UPDATE** There is an option `requiresUnpack` but it requires to provide list of dependencies... https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html

**UPDATE 2** I started evaluating of https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-alternatives